# Why are the reference not indented in the same way?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

[image: The first reference is in line with the reference heading, but then, all the other reference that follow are slightly towards the left.]

The code is:\

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=1.00 in, right=1.00 in, top=1.00 in, bottom=1.00 in]{geometry}


%To add paragraph to increase the subsections
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

1. \cite{paper1} 

2. \cite{paper2} 

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, show us a MWE with your code. Without its only guessing...

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post.

Comment: There's probably something amiss with the `paper1` bib entry such as an unusual character, really we need to see it to help.  Do you get any warnings or errors in the log? Loading the `url` package might help if it's something in the URL.

Comment: Yes, loading the `url` package fixed the error. Thanks!